# Using atomic for generating unique id

Tags: java, atomic, uniqueidentifier, java.util.concurrent

```
class ABC{
private static Random random = new Random();
private static AtomicLong uniqueLongId = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

public static long getUniqueLongId(){

            long id = uniqueLongId.incrementAndGet();
            long uniqueID = Math.abs(random.nextLong()) + id;
            return uniqueID;

            //the above code we can write in one line
    //return Math.abs(random.nextLong())+uniqueLongId.incrementAndGet();

}
}
```

Will this above method getUniqueLongId() will give me unique id in multithreaded environment. My concern here is: Knowing that uniqueLongId is atomic and assuming calling incrementAndGet() will be a thread-safe call, but the other part of code is not synchronized. will this not mean that the method getUniqueLongId() itself is not thread safe? and thus may not neccesarily return unique id?

Please explain..

Comment: Even in a single thread, your IDs are not unique. Imagine that you have id = 1 and random returns 3 => uniqueId = 4 / Next run: id = 2 and random returns 2 => uniqueId = 4 again.

Comment: yes i agree with you. but i think the chances of tat happening are still remote and tats gud enuf fr my app. i m more concerned abt 2 immediate threads generating same id using this method i.e. whether this method is thread safe or not!

Answer (score 3):

The [Java 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) write:

> Instances of `java.util.Random` are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same `java.util.Random` instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) in multithreaded designs.

So your code is thread safe in Java 7. Every operation is either a call to a thread-safe method, or operating on local variables only. And you don't require atomicity, i.e. you don't require the next sequence number to be paired with the next random number.

As (per your comment) there are no such guarantees in older versions of the API documentation, implementations could in theory be non-threadsafe. However, looking at the `src.zip` in Sun JDK 1.4.2.19 (which is the oldest version I have around), that code already uses an atomic variable, thus providing thread-safe behaviour in practice.

That said, your code has a number of other problems. Like quoted above, performance might be bad. As [assylias already wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729305/using-atomic-for-generating-unique-id#comment20606918_14729305), this approach won't give you more unique numbers than a simple `Random` would. Furthermore, [`Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28long%29) will still be negative, and a positive random number plus an id might cause overflow and wrap-around. So if you need positive numbers, you'll have to add more care. A final `uniqueID &= 0x7fffffffffffffffL` might be more suitable than the `Math.abs` along the way.

Comment: the above defination of Random being threadsafe and about ThreadLocalRandom was added in jdk1.7. m using jdk1.6 and was wondering how did i miss that!! thnx for pointing out Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE) being negative.
u mentioned "Every operation is either a call to a thread-safe method, or operating on local variables only." there r Math.abs(),assigment and addition operations which arnt thread safe. also how does use of local variable for operations makes it threadsafe? i tot synching a block of code/method would block other threads to enter it, thus making it threadsafe. hw does it wrk here?

Comment: @anzaan: Operations become non-threadsafe when they concurrently access some shared state, which might be inconsistent at some times. `Math.abs()` doesn't use shared state, so it is thread safe even if the doc's don't explicitely say so. Local variables are not shared either, so operations on these are threadsafe as well. Mutual exclusion as provided by `synchronized` blocks is only one of several ways to achieve [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). If you have no safte guarantees for `Random` in jdk1.6, you might want to synchronize on `random`.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed thread safe. MvG's answer explains why.

As noted by @assylias it might not even produce unique ids in a Single Threaded environment.

It is worth while studying the [`ObjectId`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java) generation mechanism of MongoDB.

There are four params which are introduced to ensure uniqueness.

```
a 4-byte timestamp,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter.
```

That being said, there is a [`UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class in JDK which can be used off the shelf for this purpose.

The [caveat](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6611830) being it was not thread safe until JDK 7.

Comment: You are right. I had doubts about `Random` being thread safe.
Correcting the answer.